# Using mutable function arguments to imitate C-like static variables in Python functions

Tags: python, c, mutable, static-variables

I was wondering how I could replicate static variables from C in Python. I saw a lot of posts relating to object-oriented code in Python and the use of mutable default arguments, but I was just wondering about a simple procedural example.

Here's my C example:

```
void static_variable(){
    static int x = 0;
    x++;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

and here's my Python example:

```
def static_variable(counter=[0]):
    counter[0] += 1
    print(counter[0])
```

Both examples work, however, I was wondering if using such an approach in Python carries some inherent dangers - or is it just dangerous when you are not aware of mutable arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, functions are first-class objects. Which means they can have attributes. You can simply use an attribute as your "static variable". Avoiding the pitfalls of mutable defaults and the code is much cleaner as well:

```py
def static_variable():
    # define function attribute
    if hasattr(static_variable, 'counter'):
        static_variable.counter += 1
    else:
        static_variable.counter = 1
    print(static_variable.counter)


static_variable()
static_variable()
static_variable()
```

Results:

```
1
2
3
```